# Python script with SQL Server connections runs fine in IDLE but not in command line

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc

I can run python script in IDLE but can't run in successfully in command line.
in IDLE it print out as:

```
hello
{SQL Server}
hello2
>>>
```

But in command line as "python mypython.py" it only print hello then completed.
Can anyone help what else needs to run in command line.

Below is the code.

```
import pyodbc

print ("hello")
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=testserver;'
                      'Database=database_test;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor = conn.cursor()
print ('{SQL Server}')
print ("hello2")
```

Comment: if you type in command line Python after conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=testserver;'
                      'Database=database_test;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')  the command line exit

Comment: Instead of `{SQL Server}` have you tried using `{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}`?

Comment: no matter which one. the problem is when run in command line it exit back to command line after the 'conn=....' it doesn't go to the following steps. But in IDLE it continues to the print steps. It prints out SQL SERVER and hello2.